# Turn off emoticons in Outlook Web Access

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

How can I (if can I) turn off changing text to emoticons, as I type the text, in [Outlook Web Access](https://outlook.office365.com/mail/inbox)?

[This](https://superuser.com/a/134422/156554) ten years old answer brings no solution, because it is entirely about standalone Outlook client not about OWA. [Sending e-mails as a plain text](https://superuser.com/a/806752/156554) is not an option for me; we are forced to use rich-text for e-mail signatures at my company.

I have disabled "Joyful animations", but it brought no change to emoticons:

[image]

Do I have any other option? Can I somehow get rid of that pesky yellow faces? Or becoming a dully, sad person and not using smiles (either textual or graphical) at all is the only way here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean changing into *emojis*, not *emoticons* (which are plain text).

This also annoyed the hell out of me, and I spent too much time trying to fix it (I *also* found the 10 year old "answer" you link to).

However, I finally found the answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/7bsnwy/outlookoffice_2016_or_365_how_to_revert_smileys/dpm4nwt?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). Basically, as you are typing, right when the text turns to emoji, hit the backspace key and it will revert to text. This is annoying to have to do/remember, but at least it gets the job done. In all my searches I have not found a way to generally turn of the conversion altogether.

Comment: Sounds like a blantly obvious option that I have  never figured out or tried. I went through Ctrl+Z and Esc. Both were working randomly (as a lot of things in Microsoft products). I.e. Ctrl+Z sometimes reverted adding emoji itself and sometimes it was reverting writing the whole sentence that has prepend it. I don't have access to OWA at this moment so I am accepting your answer as is. Next time, I have access to Outlook, I'll double check with your idea of using Backspace. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for "annoyed the hell out of me".  We use alphanumeric references codes with hyphens in them, and I must refer to them often in emails. Whenever I type `-B` OWA inserts a smiley-face-with-sunglasses emoji.   https://youtu.be/x1mF2ML3v_U